# Clear Event Log Database

Tags: content-manager

I'm doing a bit of maintenance and have noticed my Content Manager event log database (specifically the `dbo.EventLog` table) is getting quite large (2million rows taking 1.2Gb).

How do I clean it up?

Comment: Tridion 2013 does not have a logging db.  Another advantage to using 2013!  :)

Comment: @robrtc Unfortunately that's not an option at the moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the maintenance guide which I wrote somewhere in 2004 for the event log database we gave a SQL statement which you could use to clean it up, as this is the only database where you are allowed to manually clean up (it's content has no influence to the CM server). Julian Wraith also mentioned the same in his article on [SDL Tridion World](http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/MaintainingSDLTridiondatabases.aspx)

```
TRUNCATE TABLE EVENTLOG;
```

It's very basic, and completely empties the logging table. So as David mentioned, whether you can use is this depending on your business requirements.

Also nice to note perhaps is that in version 2013, this database is completely dropped.

Comment: That's great, thanks. Currently moving to 2013 is not an option so the logging database will have to live with the logging database for now.

Comment: yeah then it's just a simple task of cleaning it (once a year), most customers won't have a problem with clearing it completely but check in advance.

Answer (score 4):

According to [LiveContent](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_6EF48C80AD0B45FDB607C73EB639603A) you should consult your database vendor's documentation to learn how to schedule regular cleanups of the logging database.

In other words, dependent on your business requirements on how long logs need to be kept, you can schedule a task or process to truncate the data or drop & recreate the table/database before it grows beyond capacity. This would most likely end up being something like a simple SQL script.

Comment: I've no problem running a script against the table. I'd have thought there would be some sort of tool (like the `bin\PurgeTool.exe`) that doesn't require me to write a script. We are talking about the Tridion Event Log Database, not the transaction logs right?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the db, not the transaction logs. The purge tool is for the content manager queues, old versions etc. The logging database is separate and I confirmed before writing my answer with an Infrastructure Consultant that the purge tool does not do anything with it. I was a little surprised too. SDL Tridion support might have a sample script they can provide you.

Comment: Thanks David. I didn't mean to come across like I didn't believe you, just confirming! I thought there would be a simple/obvious solution. I'll contact support and if I get an answer I'll update your answer.

Comment: No worries Kevin, You didn't come across in that way at all. I'm writing answers quicker than I'd like today because I'm in a departmental meeting :)